# Why is click not being registered when an item of a NavigationView menu is tapped?

Tags: android

I have a NavigationView that comes up successfully after selecting the home icon but none of the items are able to selected. Anywhere I click on the screen, including on the items, the NavigationView just closes.

I have tried freezing the DrawerLayout so that the NavigationView menu remains displayed after any taps but the items still cannot be selected. I have tried using a NavigationItemSelectedListener and have tried inflating the menu using onCreateOptionsMenu while using onOptionsItemSelected to detect the click, though it works fine using a popup menu. I have also tried using AppBarConfiguration.

Here is the layout file code containing the NavigationView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/mainScreenToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
                android:name="com.example.scriber.fragments.MainScreenFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</layout>
```

Here is the menu file code for the NavigationView menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:id="@+id/navigationMenuGroup"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:title="@string/myEntries" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/fragment_browse"
            android:title="@string/browseFragment" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

And, here is the MainActivity code, which sets up the NavigationView:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var actionBarDrawerToggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.mainScreenToolbar)
        setTitle(R.string.myEntries)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        setUpNavigationMenu()

    }

    private fun setUpNavigationMenu() {
        binding.apply {

            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
                Util.showToast(this@MainActivity, "Clicked")
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.fragment_browse -> Navigation.findNavController(this@MainActivity, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_nav_host_fragment_to_browseFragment)
                        .also { setTitle(R.string.browseFragment) }
                }
                true
            }

            actionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this@MainActivity, drawerLayout, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer)
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> { binding.drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START) }
        }

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

    }

}
```